# Exchange 2010 SP1 Prepare-MoveRequest.Ps1 cross forest migration

Tags: exchange-2010, migration, active-directory

We are migrating to Server 20008R2 / Exchange 2010 SP1 (from server 2003, Exchange 2003), and as part of the process, have created a new forest with a different FQDN.

Now we at the end of the migration after finishing with the ADMT tool, and trying to migrate from Exchange 2003 to 2010, and the part of the process is using the Prepare-MoveRequest.Ps1 to merge attributes from source domain to target domain accounts (-UseLocalObject -OverWriteLocalObject switches).

The problem is that Prepare-MoveRequest.Ps1 script copies the source accounts as new ones, instead of merging them, as source and target account have different FQDN.

There is also a message:
WARNING: Cannot find corresponding object for XXX (source domain FQDN) in current forest. 'member' not updated.

Any idea how to solve this issue, and merge the source attributes to new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we were under time pressure, we had to erase the accounts, and first re-imported accounts with  Prepare-MoveRequest.Ps1, then re-migrated the accounts via ADMT to import SID history.

This eventually worked, but I would appreciate if anyone could advice on this for the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are two switches that will allow merging when users exist in the target domain.  In my case the source and target account names were different, so I required an include file for ADMT, but for this preparemove I specified Identity using smtp address which it recognized in source and target and did the merge perfectly based on that.

They are `-UseLocalObject` followed by `-OverwriteLocalObject`

```
.\Prepare-MoveRequest.ps1 -RemoteForestDomainController dc401.dc.contoso.com 
-RemoteForestCredential $RemoteCredentials -LocalForestDomainController phiads001.dt.inc -LocalForestCredential $LocalCredentials -UseLocalObject -OverwriteLocalObject -Verbose -Identity wbrown@contoso.com

VERBOSE: Local ad account with dupplicate proxy addresses found: CN=Woody Brown,OU=Users,OU=Philadelphia,DC=dt,DC=inc
VERBOSE: Merging Mailbox properties to local MailUser
VERBOSE: Setting msExchMailboxGUID to 136aef07-5869-415e-ae0e-bbe69963593b
VERBOSE: Setting proxyAddresses to x500:/o=DealerTrack/ou=Exchange Administrative Group
(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Woody Brown8d2 x500:/o=DealerTrack/ou=Exchange Administrative Group
(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Woody Brown753677056d53 X400:c=US;a= ;p=contoso;o=Exchange;s=Brown;g=Woody;
SMTP:wbrown@contoso.com
Appending x500:/o=contoso/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=wbrown to proxyAddresses of Object(CN=Woody Brow
n,OU=Users,OU=Philadelphia,DC=dt,DC=inc) in Local forest.
VERBOSE: OverwriteLocalObject specified. Updating MailUser with with attributes from source MBX(CN=Woody
Brown,CN=Users,DC=dc,DC=contoso,DC=com).
VERBOSE: Setting displayName to Woody Brown
VERBOSE: Setting Mail to wbrown@contoso.com
VERBOSE: Setting mailNickName to wbrown
VERBOSE: Setting msExchMailboxGuid to 136aef07-5869-415e-ae0e-bbe69963593b
VERBOSE: Setting countryCode to 0
VERBOSE: Setting givenName to Woody
VERBOSE: Setting Sn to Brown
VERBOSE: Setting textEncodedORAddress to c=US;a= ;p=contoso;o=Exchange;s=Brown;g=Woody;
Preparation for wbrown@contoso.com done. Local recipient info Merged.
1 mailbox(s) ready to move.
[PS] C:\scripts>
```